# adb and fastboot drivers for Xperia ARC S

Tags: rom-flashing, flashtool

I am trying to flash `boot.img` via Flashtool 0.9.16.1 but when i connect my xperia arc S in "Fastboot" mode then i get error message like

"Device drivers are not installed, you can find it in drivers folder"

I installed `Flashtool-drivers.exe` but no success.
Still error is same.

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Do you mean [this one](http://d-h.st/Wyk)? You should add links to what you've installed so you won't get duplicate answers...

Comment: The latest package is [this](http://doomlord.xperia-files.com/download.php?dlid=Rmxhc2h0b29sLWRyaXZlcnMtMS41LTIwMTQwMzE4), but the first link worked for my Xperia Z,